# How to compare items in array using index numbers?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, if-statement, comparison

How can I compare one item in array to it's next or previous item using index numbers Take the code below as example

```
const arr = [
  {
    name: "A",
    marks: 20,
  },
  {
    name: "B",
    marks: 25,
  },
  {
    name: "C",
    marks: 30,
  },
];
```

So how can I compare B with A or C in an **if** statement using index numbers to get something done?

Comment: It is not so clear what exactly do you want? Please be specific and you should add what should be your expected result?

Comment: Note: If you are using index then you can use `i-1` and `i+1` for `previous` and `next` respectively...

Comment: For instance if I'm trying to create a graph so i wants to make bars green and red based on the comparison with previous item in array(incline or decline) so if some numeric property of an object in an array is greater than same property of previous object than i wants to make bar green else i want to make bar red.

Comment: what about the first property then. Should it be `red` or `green`? Because there is no property to compare it with.

Comment: what loop are you using here to iterate on the array

Comment: I'm using forEach array method i don't mind how first property will look

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `forEach` then you can do as:

> NOTE: Handle the first case where `i === 0` according to your need

```js
const arr = [
  {
    name: "A",
    marks: 20,
  },
  {
    name: "B",
    marks: 25,
  },
  {
    name: "C",
    marks: 30,
  },
];

const result = [];
arr.forEach((obj, index, sourceArr) => {
  if (index === 0) result.push(undefined);
  else {
    obj.marks > sourceArr[index - 1].marks
      ? result.push("green")
      : result.push("red");
  }
});

console.log(result);
```